# Need clear understanding of Home vs Back events

Tags: android

I would like to know the "idea / use" of the home versus the back button. I mean obviously the  home button takes you to the home screen and the back button takes you to the previous screen. What I am trying to understand is what the users / development community expect.

In other words when a user hits home in my application should I handle that event and terminate the application? Is that what the user has grown to expect or just the opposite?

Same for the back button. Do users expect the screen being departed from to be lost much like a web page would be?

What I am getting at is trying to make sure my app behaves consistent with what the user community has grown to expect.

TIA
JB

Answer (score 2):

**Home Button** will put application in onPause() -> onStop() , again when you relaunch application, the activity will execute the method: onRestart() -> onStart() -> onResume() -> i.e. [activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

and

**Back button** finishes or kills the current Activity on click of back button and jump back to the previous Activity which is in stack.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd say that pressing home is like minimising on a desktop. So I would expect the app to return to where it was.
If it acts like this then I can easily switch between apps if I need to get information from them.
Pressing back should take me backwards through the things I was doing in the app and when I reach the end of the stack it should close.

Answer (score 1):

home button pressing causes an intent that is used by the the launcher app to show itself .

back button is a real event that can be caught within the current app .

in general , home button should hide all apps and go to the launcher , while back button should go back to the previous screen the user saw (finish the activity or dismiss the dialog) , and go to the previous app (task ) in case the current one doesn't have any more screens to show .

Answer (score 1):

The community expects that if you press the home button, your app will go to the background and be resumeable from there. Multitasking is in the core of the Android OS. To finish your activity or app when home button is pressed is unusual to android users.

The back button is when you want to go one step back, like in the browser as you said. If you are know to IOS it will act like when you press the back button there in the top left corner.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know the "idea / use" of the home versus the back
> button

Let me Discuss for **Back** Button First.

> **The back button behavior is inconsistent.**

for Users, it is very easy to use.

for Developer, to understand what actually pressing the back button does it isn't so easy.

> The back button can perform any of the following actions as Officially said by Android site :
>
> 1. Go back to previous screen (activity)
> 2. Dismiss a popup
> 3. Terminate a long running process
> 4. Close on-screen keyboard
> 5. Go to previous page on browser
> 6. Exit the running app when on the last activity
> 7. Return to previous app when on the last activity and the app was launched through intent from another app

**When Problem Occur with BACK button?**

> An added problem comes when trying to understand when the back button
> cancels a running operation and when not. For example, when installing
> apps from Android market tapping back takes users to previous screen
> and leaves the installation process running in background. I know
> there's a rule that back cancels operations that are presented users
> as popup progress indicators and any other cases it is used to
> navigate. But is that what users expect? Do users have to think before
> pressing back to understand what is going to happen?

**Home Button**

> Home button will take users to home screen and swiping in the
> multitasking menu will kill the apps if needed. As on ICS on new
> phones all the buttons are on-screen the back button could simply get
> disabled when user reaches the last activity if the app was launched
> from launcher icon. This would make some of the confusion to make away
> but still wouldn't solve all the problems.

Finally , **Don't Make Users Think** Navigation is some what more important. `Users should always know where they will endup without thinking.`

I don't think there are easy answers for this problem but I think it may help you to find workaround for your problem according to your app.